# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.PowerShell.Security' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, fusion

I'm running PowerShell from a C# console app.  My dev box has PowerShell 3.0 - the target machines will probably have v2.0.  My project file has a reference to the assembly:

```
<Reference Include="System.Management.Automation" />
```

which seems to be the recommended way.  I'm getting a System.IO.FileNotFoundException when I call runspace.Open():

```
using (var runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(initialSessionState))
{
    runspace.AvailabilityChanged += runspace_AvailabilityChanged;
    runspace.StateChanged += runspace_StateChanged;
    runspace.Open();
    ...
}
```

The exception details are:

Message: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.PowerShell.Security' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

FusionLog:

```
=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = MYDOMAIN\MyUser
LOG: DisplayName = Microsoft.PowerShell.Security
 (Partial)
WRN: Partial binding information was supplied for an assembly:
WRN: Assembly Name: Microsoft.PowerShell.Security | Domain ID: 1
WRN: A partial bind occurs when only part of the assembly display name is provided.
WRN: This might result in the binder loading an incorrect assembly.
WRN: It is recommended to provide a fully specified textual identity for the assembly,
WRN: that consists of the simple name, version, culture, and public key token.
WRN: See whitepaper http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=109270 for more information and common solutions to this issue.
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Users/MyUser.MYDOMAIN/Projects/PoSh/PoShRunner1/bin/Debug/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
Calling assembly : System.Management.Automation, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Users\MyUser.MYDOMAIN\Projects\PoSh\PoShRunner1\bin\Debug\PoShRunner1.vshost.exe.Config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/MyUser.MYDOMAIN/Projects/PoSh/PoShRunner1/bin/Debug/Microsoft.PowerShell.Security.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/MyUser.MYDOMAIN/Projects/PoSh/PoShRunner1/bin/Debug/Microsoft.PowerShell.Security/Microsoft.PowerShell.Security.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/MyUser.MYDOMAIN/Projects/PoSh/PoShRunner1/bin/Debug/Microsoft.PowerShell.Security.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/MyUser.MYDOMAIN/Projects/PoSh/PoShRunner1/bin/Debug/Microsoft.PowerShell.Security/Microsoft.PowerShell.Security.EXE.
```

If I turn off Common Language Runtime Exceptions in VS 2012, I get

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.DllNotFoundException' occurred in System.Management.Automation.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Management.Automation.Host.HostException' occurred in System.Management.Automation.dll
```

in the output log.

I've had a look at the document referenced in the fusion log but most of it doesn't seem to apply to this case or help much with my understanding.  Microsoft.PowerShell.Security is in the GAC so what's the problem?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you compiled against the powershell 3.0 system.management.automation (s.m.a.) assembly - 3.0.0.0 - instead of the powershell 2.0 s.m.a which is 1.0.0.0.

Open your project, browse to the 1.0.0.0 version and recompile. PowerShell 3.0 installs both 1.0.0.0 and 3.0.0.0 s.m.a assemblies to the GAC. Then your program will work on systems with either 2.0 or 3.0 versions of powershell.